# Setting function pointer in class constructor... '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, function-pointers

I am trying to set a function pointer on the constructor of a class.

I am receiving the following error:

Error   1   error C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression

Can anyone please advise why this is happening (code below)?

Edit:

This example of the problem better shows my situation. I am ONLY able to change MyClass. I cannot touch MyBase or it's contents.

```
class MyBase
{
public:

    void (*MyFunctionPointer)(int args);

};

class MyClass : public MyBase
{
public:

    void MyFunction(int args)
    {
    }

    MyClass()
    {
        MyFunctionPointer = &MyFunction;
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyClass temp;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [relevant FAQ entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/fnptr-vs-memfnptr-types.html)

Comment: @FredOverflow Thanks. I read it but I still don't get it :(

Comment: Have you tried `void (MyClass::*MyFunctionPointer)(int args);`?

Comment: That would be a change to the pointer definition, which I can't change (in my actual code). It resides in a base class. Is there a way to only change the function that I set the pointer with, please?

Comment: in that case you need a `static` method.

Comment: So it seems... but I need to call a non static member straight afterwards. Ummmmmmmm. Any other suggestions? I can change MyBase so long as it doesnt involve referencing MyClass within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers to method functions are different type from pointers to global functions and static methods.

```
class MyClass;

class MyBase
{
public:

    void (MyClass::* MyFunctionPointer)(int);

};

class MyClass : public MyBase
{
public:

    void MyFunction(int args)
    {
    }

    MyClass()
    {
        MyFunctionPointer = &MyClass::MyFunction;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MyClass temp;

    return 0;
}
```

If you cannot change `MyBase`, then you cannot use the member `MyFunctionPointer` because it is of type pointer to global function or static method. If you tell us what it is exactly what are you trying to achieve, maybe we can help you.

Edit 2 (op edited):

What I am trying to do is write some code which would give me this functionality. Ie, a base class with a function pointer which can be set to a non-member function (temp1)... or inherited from a class which contains a non-static member which can be called (temp2).

```
class MyBase
{
public:

    void (*MyFunctionPointer)(int args);

};

class MyClass : public MyBase
{
public:

    void MyFunction(int args)
    {
    }

    void Bind(void (*myFunctionPointer)(int args))
    {
        MyFunctionPointer = myFunctionPointer;
    }
};

void MyFunction2(int args)
{
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MyBase temp1;
    temp1.MyFunctionPointer = &MyFunction2;        // <<-- ok
    temp1.MyFunctionPointer(0);

    MyClass temp2;
    temp2.Bind(&temp2.MyFunction);  // <<-- compile error
    temp2.MyFunctionPointer(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:

As said before, pointer to functions and pointer to methods are different types. That is a pointer to function cannot be assigned a method address and a pointer to method cannot be assigned a function address. You could have 2 pointers, one of type pointer to function and another one pointer to method and a boolean value which tells you which one of the two you use. Or you could use templates.

Comment: Ummm, MyBase knows nothing of MyClass in my code... and can't :(

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A sort of event... triggered from the base class calling a method existing in the parent class.

Comment: The classes in my actual code are already templated. How would that work please?

Answer (score 1):

`MyFunction` is a *member* function, but `MyFunctionPointer` is a basic function pointer.

You should investigate the syntax for producing [a pointer-to-member-function](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/function.html#fqa-33.1).

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get it. I can't change MyFunctionPointer's definition but I can change MyFunction. Is there something I can do to get this to work? Thanks

Comment: @Beakie: You can't change it to fix it? Why's that? If you're not "allowed" to fix the problem then you can't fix the problem. You'll have to make `MyFunction` `static` (which is effectively the same as making it a non-member, in this situation). Member functions are special beasts and are not compatible with basic function pointers due to their requirement for an object instance context.

Comment: Using the edited example above, if I were to change the definition in MyBase to ... void (MyBase::*MyFunctionPointer)(int args); ... What would I set it to in MyClass in order for it to point to the method in MyClass? Thanks

Comment: @Beakie: Did you read the material I linked you to? Learning how to perform research is important.